# receving and sending message to mqseries server from .net core

Tags: dll, .net-core, ibm-mq

i would like to connect to mqseries server having this info

1. the queue 's name :"myqueue"
2. connection name:"myconnectionName"
3. client channel :"mychannel"
4. server name:"myServerName"

   do i also need to know the queuemanager? or can i use "default" and i am also getting this error message

> Unable to load DLL 'mqic32.dll' or one of its dependencies:
>   The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)'

```
        static MQQueueManager queueManager;
        static MQQueueManager qManager;
        static MQQueue queue;
        MQMessage queueMessage;
        MQGetMessageOptions queueGetMessageOptions;
        MQPutMessageOptions queuePutMessageOptions;
        static string QueueName;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Connect();
        }
         static void Connect()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json", true, true).Build();

            // Read the Mqseries "connection string" from App.config file.
            var queueManagerName = builder["queueManagerName"];
            var MQChannel = builder["MQChannel"];
            var  queueName = builder["QueueName"];
            string connectionName = builder["ConnectionName"];
            MQAccess(queueName, "Default", connectionName, MQChannel);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to MQ Queue Manager");
        }
        public static void MQAccess(string queueName, string queueManager, string connection, string channel)
        {
            QueueName = queueName;

            qManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManager, channel, connection);

            queue = qManager.AccessQueue(QueueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
        }
```

Comment: You need to make a managed connection if you want to stay inside .net, otherwise it will try to load native code (C dlls) to make the connection. By default the .net MQ code will call through to the C layer (MQIC*.dll) unless you ask it to make the connection itself and stay inside the .net layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET core support was added in MQ v9.1.1. Again as @JasonE said, you need to use MQ .NET Managed mode only.

Sample code:

```
Hashtable properties;
MQQueueManager queueManager = null;
try {
    properties = new Hashtable();
    properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
    properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
    properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
    properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
    properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, userName);
    properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, pwd);

    MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);

}catch(MQException mqex) {
 // Console out exception
}
```

Comment: is there  a nuget  like this Managed IBM WebSphere MQ Client for .NET for .net core otherwise i am getting errors on MQC

Comment: What assembly are you referencing in your application?

Comment: i have a using IBM.WMQ coming from WebSphereMqClient(8.0.0.7)

Comment: you meant i am using amqmnet.dll instead of amqmdnetstd.dll?

Comment: For .NET Core applications amqmdnetstd.dll to be used.

Comment: @isa did you find the solution for amqmdnetstd.dll?